# AngularJS form in WebDriver

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There is a file upload form with data type `input[type="text" i]`.
I would like to select and upload a file without `Robot class` and `KeyEvent`. Class in HTML looks as follows: `class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched"`.

I try to upload a file without opening of a file picker window, so use the following code.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("myfilepath");
```

I got an exception and the same when I use `XPath` to identify an object and pass file path.

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Similar site and form: https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/#2

Comment: Possible to have a look at the page?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to fill the value of element that is not visible. You should scroll to that element first to fill it. Also not sure about your css selector `myfilepath` - it's just an example, or do you have `myfilepath` component/directive?

Comment: @MartinAdámek : Not needed to scroll, it is visible after page is loaded. `myfilepath` variable contains the exact path to the file on my computer.

Comment: Well but you are using it as CSS selector via `By.cssSelector("myfilepath")`...

Comment: You should put there CSS selector of the file input, and set the path as its value.

Comment: I fixed it, but same effect.

Comment: Can you post 5-10 lines of html code, So that we can support you.

Comment: @Yash: Site is similar to this one: https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/#2

Comment: you need to use java robot class to upload file. for the you have provided.

Comment: @Yash : I use it at this time too, but I would like to replace it with a smarter solution, which doesn't require file picker window.

Comment: `type="file"` means you cannot send text for it. you need to use robot only

Answer (score 2):

**using javascript we can achieve this**

**javascript code:**

```
var test=document.querySelector('your css selector');

test.setAttribute("value","your path value");
```

write javascript code in string and passed to javascriptExecutor along with csspathselector,file path value

**Selenium code:**

```
String js = "var test=document.querySelector(arguments[0]);test.setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);";
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript(js, "yourcssSelectorPath","filepath");
```

Comment: It throw error: `Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: sorry i missed to close after argument[0] ,try this

Comment: String js=" var test=document.querySelector(arguments[0]);test.setAttribute("value",arguments[1]);"

Comment: _error: ';' expected
        String js=" var test=document.querySelector(arguments[0]);test.setAttribute(‌​"value",arguments[1]‌​);";_

Comment: String js="var test=document.querySelector(arguments[0]);test.setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);";
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  jse.executeScript(js, "#main > div:nth-child(5) > div > form > input[type=\"text\"]:nth-child(2)","rajutest");

Comment: i tried the above code its working for me.check once.if you have any issue let me know.

Comment: I got error again: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157432/discussion-between-raju-and-plaidshirt).

Answer (score 1):

You should select the `input[file]` first (e.g. via CSS selector), and set the path to the file as its value:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.your-file-input-class")).sendKeys("/my/file/path");
```

You need to find the element via `input.your-file-input-class` first. Adjust the CSS selector based on your markup.

Best way to be sure you fill the right input is to add some class or id on the element. You could also use `input[type="text"]` as selector, if you know there will be just one file input on the page.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys("/my/file/path");
```

Btw you also noted in the comments, that `myfilepath` is a variable containing the path. If so, drop the quotes, you can not use it as a string value:

```
String myfilepath = "/path/to/file";

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys(myfilepath);
```

If the error preserves, you should try to wait until the element is visible, that could help too:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); // 1 min timeout
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"text\"]")));
el.sendKeys(myfilepath);
```

Comment: I use `WebDriver 3.6.0` and `setAttribute` method cannot be resolved.

Comment: Looks like you need to do this in JS, will update the answer.

Comment: so the method on java element is called `sendKeys`, `setAttribute` is from js DOM element, sorry for the confusion...

Comment: I get the same error as earlier: `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible`

Comment: Also, is the element really visible (are you able to inspect it via chrome dev tools?)

Comment: Btw is it really simple file upload field (`<input type="file">`), or do you have multiupload field, or some JS uploader on top of it? This solution will probably work just with simple file inputs...

Comment: Yes, field is visible and can upload only 1 file.

Comment: Have you tried the wait example I added to the end of my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157385/discussion-between-plaidshirt-and-martin-adamek).